# Find all dependencies of a list of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

We have a list of 51 stored procedures used in our application.

I need to find out the names of all the functions and stored procedures called by those stored procs

Is there a quick way to find out what our stored procedures are calling?

I tried using **sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities** as below

```
SELECT 
referencing_schema_name +'.'+ referencing_entity_name AS ReferencedEntityName,
referencing_class_desc AS ReferencingEntityDescription 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.sp_GetPayRunDetails', 'OBJECT');
GO
```

but I am hoping that there is a way to check all 50 stored procs and get detailed information about what other objects (stored procs, and functions) that they call...

I don't want to do this manually is because I also need recursive dependencies for the stored procs and functions that are called...

Comment: This can only work if *no* dynamic SQL code is used (EXEC '...') in the SPs. Are you looking for recursive dependencies, e.g. if A uses B, and B uses C, do you want to see A as using C as well? What about table and view usage?

Comment: @Lucero: Hi, thanks for responding - I do need recursive dependencies, but I only need stored procs, and functions for this project. I don't think there are any dynamic calls

Comment: With only 51 sprocs this would take you what, less than 2 hours to do manually?  Unless you need to do this on a recurring basis the best use of your time is to probably just do it manually.

Comment: @iamdave Manually doing that would be a pain... let the machine do the work! :)

Comment: @iamdave: True but I also need recursive dependencies so that the systems analyst can identify bottlenecks and performance enhancements

Comment: @Lucero  Making it work given all the caveats you have pointed out will take a while and then you need to actually verify the results before making decisions based on them.  If this is a regular task then I fully agree!  But as a one off?  Only if you have the time to spare.

Comment: @OurManInBananas  Doing the recursive parts will be very easy for a person to identify and record as you go through them.  Just record the details you require in a sensible excel format and you're fine.

Comment: @iamdave The query in my response took just a couple of minutes to write, and it was fun :) - and tracking recursive dependencies in Excel... no thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query might do the trick for you:

```
WITH cteDependencies AS (
    SELECT e.referencing_id object_id, e.referencing_id, e.referenced_id, e.referenced_schema_name, e.referenced_entity_name
    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies e
    WHERE e.referencing_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_GetPayRunDetails')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.object_id, e.referencing_id, e.referenced_id, e.referenced_schema_name, e.referenced_entity_name
    FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies e
    JOIN cteDependencies d ON d.referenced_id = e.referencing_id AND e.referenced_id <> e.referencing_id
)
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id) source_name, d.*
    FROM cteDependencies d
    JOIN sys.all_objects o ON d.referenced_id = o.object_id
    WHERE o.[type] IN ('P','FN','TF'); -- for a list of types see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178618.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
```

Note that it will fail on circular references; if you have such, you need to track the dependency path (for instance in a XML column) and skip items which are repeated.

You can change the "source" by altering the `OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_GetPayRunDetails')` filter to include the SPs you want to analyze.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify that I would change `OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_GetPayRunDetails')` to something like **OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_GetPayRunDetails', 'sp2', 'sp3'...)**?

Comment: Either with `IN (OBJECT_ID('sp1'), OBJECT_ID('sp2'), ...)` for explicitly querying SPs, or more general with a `JOIN sys.all_objects o ON e.referencing_id = o.object_id AND o.[type] = 'P'` to get all SPs for instance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a function. Modify it as per your means. It manages self-references

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDependents(    
 @ObjectName AS SYSNAME    
)    
RETURNS @result TABLE ( Seq INT IDENTITY, ObjectName SYSNAME, Hierarchy VARCHAR(128) , objNameStr varchar(max) )    
AS    
BEGIN    
;WITH Obj AS (    

SELECT DISTINCT s.id  AS ParentID, s.DepID AS ObjectID, o1.Name AS ParentName, o2.Name AS ChildName,    
       QUOTENAME(sch1.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o1.Name) + '(' + RTRIM(o1.type) + ')' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    
       AS ParentObject,     
     QUOTENAME(sch2.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o2.Name) + '(' + RTRIM(o2.type) + ')' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ObjectName,    
     o2.Name as objNameStr    
FROM sys.sysdepends s    
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o1 ON s.id = o1.object_id    
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch1 ON sch1.schema_id = o1.schema_id    
INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o2 on s.DepID = o2.object_id    
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch2 ON sch2.schema_id = o2.schema_id    
where o2.type not in ('u') and  s.id <>s.DepID --Self Reference  ko hata...   
), cte AS (    
SELECT    
0 AS lvl,    
ParentID,    
ObjectId,    
ParentObject,    
ObjectName,    
CAST(ObjectID AS VARBINARY(512)) AS Sort    
, objNameStr    

FROM obj WHERE ParentName = @ObjectName    
UNION ALL    
SELECT    
p.lvl+ 1,    
c.ParentID,    
c.ObjectId,    
c.ParentObject,    
c.ObjectName,    
CAST(p.sort + CAST(c.ObjectID AS VARBINARY(16))    
AS VARBINARY(512)), c.objNameStr    

FROM cte p    
INNER JOIN obj c ON p.ObjectID = c.ParentID    
)    
INSERT INTO @result (ObjectName, Hierarchy,objNameStr)    
SELECT    
ObjectName,    
'|-' + REPLICATE('-',(lvl * 4)) + ObjectName,    
objNameStr    
FROM cte    
ORDER BY Sort    
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);    

RETURN    
END
```

Comment: Note that the use of `sys.sysdepends` is deprecated. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325.aspx